# Writing to excel file and using too many rows

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a problem with writing from a VB.NET application to excel. I am basically trying to write the numbers 1-2000000 into excel. The problem is that excel can only hold 1048575 rows and so I cut it at 1000000 to make it simpler. I am trying to write the first million numbers into the first column and the second million into the second column. e.g

1       |       1000001

2       |       1000002

...     |       ...

1000000 | 2000000

```
For i = 1 to 2000000 Step 1
    'sheet.cells(row,column) these are the parameters for cells()
    sheet.cells(i Mod 1000000 , 2 * Math.floor(i / 1000000) + 1)
Next
```

I run the program and I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Where am I wrong? I've tried using google, and it seems that the problem is that its trying to write into a cell thats not there, and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Rinslep

Comment: At which value of `i` does this error occur?

Comment: Should have mentioned that :/ At 1000000 just as its meant to switch coulmns

Comment: (i -1) Mod 1000000 +1, to avoid 0

Comment: Well, It turns out that i'm an idiot and excel is not 0 based...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that excel is not 0 based and so:

```
((i-1) Mod 1000000) + 1
```

this fixes it.

*thanks user3964075 :)*